# Unity Editor Scene View does not match built executable

Tags: unity, resolution, ui-design

I'm trying to make my game resolution independent. I'm using Unity's 4.6 UI, and I've got custom resolutions defined at 1280 x 720, 1600 x 900, and 1920 x 1080. In-editor, if I swap between any of these resolutions, the observed scene doesn't change. It looks like this:
[image]

I then build an executable (set to only allow 16x9 resolutions), and run this scene. On 1280 x 720 (as selected from the resolution dialog), I get this:
[image]

While on 1920 x 1080 (as selected from the resolution dialog), I get this:
[image]

Which matches the editor view. (Ignore the character sprites; those are in worldspace on a separate camera and aren't relevant to this question).

What is it about the executable that causes lower resolutions to be "zoomed in" like this, even if that lower resolution is the Reference Resolution for the Canvas Scaler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a [bug specific to the version](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/canvas-scaler-broken-in-unity-5-3-1f1.380809/) of Unity I was using (5.3.1f1.).

After updating, the scaling began working as expected.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer so others with a similar problem can see in the search results that a solution was found.

Comment: @DMGregory No worries! Just an issue of not being under the 2 day limit when I originally posted.